# Name Sorting logic in File System

Tags: filesystems, file-manager

I want to name a folder so that the file manager list it at first place on the top, if sort-by-name  option is enabled.

What name should I give to my folder?

I know that if name of folder starts with numeric value then it is listed at first place.

beside numeric value is there any special character whose preference is higher that numeric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An underscore will place your folder at the top. We prefix an underscore to error log folder names so they are easier to spot.

Comment: thanks. So you mean that underscore weight is greater than any other character. Can you you give me any source because I want mention it in my thesis.

Comment: @Syed This question might give you some more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290541/what-is-the-first-character-in-the-sort-order-used-by-windows-explorer